# Why do we index as opposed to using variables?

Tags: set-theory

For example, if we have some set containing sets, A, could we label the members of this set A, x,y,z, or a_1, a_2, a_3? Are both forms of notation used interchangeably ?

Comment: I have wondered about this too, especially if the summation is only 3 or 4 terms (like dx, dy, dz).

Comment: I think some variable x is supposed to have “multi-representation” capabilities. For instance when defining a set with the abstraction method we often use x to represent more then one member of that set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choice of labelling generally comes down to:

1. Convenience
2. Clarity
3. Context
4. Convention
5. Author preference

There is nothing fundamental in the choice of using $x, y, z$ or $a_1, a_2, a_3$. Using $x, y, z$ might make it easier to distinguish between them, but it also carries a suggestion that they might be representing real numbers / coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^3$. On the other hand, $a_1, a_2, a_3$ makes it easier to make reference to $a_i$ as a generic member of the set (e.g. for indexing in a sum), and also makes it easier to extend things to larger sets by just increasing the maximum index.